# Div with background-image dissappears when added display:inline in css

Tags: css, alignment, inline

I have a dropdown list aligned with textbox and i want to add a div that has a classed called ok , this class adds a backgroundimage to that div.

The problem is that the image is not aligned with the other content.

```
 <div class="form-group form-inline"  id="divReservaCanchas" runat="server" >

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCanchas" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"Width="175px"
                    DataTextField="16" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCanchas_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Canchas</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <div class="ok" ></div>
```

Here is the css.

```
.ok
{
background-image: url(../img/Glyphicons/ok.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
height: 25px;
width: 25px; 
display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'aligned'? Where is the image supposed to sit?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set width and height to `inline` elements. To apply width and height, set css property `display` to `inline-block`.

**Change:**

```
display:inline;
```

To

```
display:inline-block;
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26Q6G/2/)**